# How to combine MembershipReboot and Thinktecture.IdentityServer?

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server, membershipreboot

I was able to download and run locally, the MembershipReboot project.  I was able to download and run on our test server the Thinktecture IdentityServer project.  No major issues with each one by themselves.  Now, I want to use MembershipReboot as part of my IdentityServer.  I downloaded the sample code and I think I see where code replaces code.  However, I'm blind as to what happens with the database.  Which database becomes the master?  Or do I run something to "upgrade" the IS database?  How about a tutorial or guide for dummies like me?  I'm given a six month project of building a SSO and asked to complete it in 5 days.

Comment: As a follow up, I was finally able to setup the MembershipReboot as the datastore for IdentityServer fairly easily, once I figured out how.  Now, I'm trying to figure out how to get all the goodness of the MembershipReboot login while still issuing a token via IdentityServer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two databases with IdentityServer v2: One for the IdSrv configuration and another for the identity database (MR in your case). So in short, they are configured separately.

Comment: A bit closer to clear, still wrapping my head around this.  We're going from zero (old school form and query) to 60 in a week when we really need 6 weeks.  Plus, having to learn EF, plus...  If anyone has a guide for dummies with step by step that would be great.  Too bad ISv3 is just starting out since it has this integration out of the box.